# Default focus on interactive element in Android with external keyboard

Tags: android, navigation, keyboard, accessibility, talkback

I have an Activity in my Android app with 2 `TextView` (non-interactive elements) and 1 `Button` (interactive element)

This is how it looks :-

[image]

With talkback enabled, the focus is going from `TextView1` (Hello) -> `TextView2` (World) -> `Button` (Next)
This behavior is looking fine to me.

But as per Android's Accessibility guidelines for Navigating through keyboard, I want the `TextView` elements to be non-focusable and the default focus should reach the first interactive element (in this case, my `Button`) on the screen.

I want to know how can I achieve this without impacting the behavior during Talkback ON?

This is the content of my layout xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="World"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share a reference for the keyboard guidelines? I'm concerned that there has been a miscommunication. If a user were blind, for example, wouldn't it be considered equitable design for them to experience the app from top to bottom like other folks? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_design

Surely by forcing focus on the button screen reader users would be forced to navigate up to read the content?

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon The documents is shared by my org internally. So, can't share. I agree to your point for the users who are blind. But what about the users who are using external keyboard (maybe due to mobility issues)? They are able to see the static context. Why the focus of keyboard elements needs to go through them?